# What is the difference between substring() and substr() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Both substring() and substr() give the same results when executed in MySQL. So, are they the same?
Which one of them should be preferred over the other?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No difference. Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)!

Answer (score 2):

A simple look into the MySQL documentation shows:

```
SUBSTR() is a synonym for SUBSTRING().
```

Take a look yourself, as a developer you *have to* start reading the documentations of the tools you use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html